# How to use date in oozie workflow

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator, oozie-workflow

I have an oozie coordinator and runs an oozie workflow. One of the action in my workflow is to run a bash script file and I need to use year, month and day in the bash script. From what I understand, `${year}`, `${month}` etc are variables that are available in the coordinator, but how can I make them available in my bash scripts as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you call your shell script with arguments from oozie such as

```
sample_shell.sh year month
```

Then create a ooziejob.properties file which contains the definition of the arguments.

```
oozie.wf.application.path=hdfs://localhost:8020/foo/bar
jobTracker=localhost:8032
nameNode=hdfs://localhost:8020
year=${year}
month=${month}
```

inside your shell script you can access them as normal arguments

```
#!/bin/bash
#echo year
echo "Arg 0: $0"
#echo month
echo "Arg 1: $1"
```

Comment: I did something similar but ${year} is not available in workflow, it's only available in coordinator

Comment: @HHH it looks like I thought it would be simpler than it actually is. I've had success passing arguments between shell scripts in a similar fashion. Here is a link that describes better how to do what you need to.https://rogerhosto.com/apache-oozie-shell-script-example/